# Is the "permissions" tag really just about filesystem permissions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the description of the [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/permissions) reads:

> Short for "file system permissions" - access control based on user, group, or global access.

But is it true? If I ask why doesn't `strace -p 1` work without being root, or why `ping` needs to be setuid, what tag should I choose?

Answer (score -1):

I would say that all those questions are about user management: how to prevent/allow users/groups from doing X. I would say that the questions should be reviewed and all the cases where user management applies, replace the tag. There are some tagged also with other permission based services (apache, samba) which has nothing to do with the UNIX user system or about filesystems. Those will need the tag removed and tagged with something else.